# A gradle plugin that adds dependencies and a sample project in the same project

Tags: java, plugins, gradle, dependencies

I want to create, in the same project, so that my IDE allows me to code them all, the following subprojects :

- a java package
- a gradle plugin that adds a dependency on the java project (artifact)
- a gradle sample that uses this plugin

The problem is that the sample, to be evaluated, will need to use the plugin, then the plugin will add the dependency.

BUT, to compile the java package, I need all the subprojects to be evaluated...including the sample. And the sample can't be evaluated as it needs the java dependency...

How can I do ?

I didn't find anyway to get all 3 subprojects in the same project. I tried configuration on demand but the buildScript of the sample still is evaluated. My only work around is to remove the sample subproject from the project.

Comment: What do you mean by "project"? What IDE?

Comment: I don't get what is difference between java package and sample. Is it like crashlytics library, crashlytics gradle plugin, sample that uses crashlytics?

Comment: @chrylis : project is gradle project.

Comment: @EugenMartynov a sample is an example sub project that uses the plugin, and as such, will receive a new dependency on the java project. Exactly like crashlytics (that I don't know of).

Comment: Prepare a minimal working example. It will be much easier to help.

Comment: Examples: 
https://github.com/stephanenicolas/injectresource
https://github.com/stephanenicolas/injectextra
https://github.com/stephanenicolas/injectview

Comment: What is plugin doing? I wonder what is conceptual difference with ButterKnife process?

Comment: Butter knife doesn't have a gradle plugin that injects the dependency of butterknife to your project. Hugo is closer and Hugo doesn't include the example in the project.

Comment: I looked to the injectview project. So gradle plugin adds dependency to you library as well it generates some source. I'm not big expert but why not to have annotation processor which standard java way and ask user to include compile dependency for you library manually?

Comment: I don't see the point @EugenMartynov